# Xamarin Forms unable to change pages

Tags: c#, xamarin

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace mySolution
{
    public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
    {

        public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        void StartClicked(object sender, EventArgs e) 
        {
            NavigationPage page = new NavigationPage(new Page1());
            MainPage = page;
            //App.change(page);
            //await Homepage.PopToRootAsync();
        }


    }
}
```

I'm making an app and in the same solution I added another Xamarin forms file called "Page1". When I try to do what is uncommented above I get this error:

```
MainPage is a type but is used like a variable
```

I have been stuck messing around with this for hours. How do I change pages? I've tried the PushAsync, but It doesn't work for the android device I am using. I am about to lose hope and just go to Android Studio.

Edit: Here is my code in App

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace mySolution
{
    public partial class App : Application
    {
        public App ()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            MainPage = new mySolution.MainPage();
            //Page1 = new mySolution.Page1(); 
        }
        /*
        public static void change(NavigationPage n)
        {
            MainPage = n;
        }  */

        protected override void OnStart ()
        {
            // Handle when your app starts
        }

        protected override void OnSleep ()
        {
            // Handle when your app sleeps
        }

        protected override void OnResume ()
        {
            // Handle when your app resumes
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You set the `MainPage` at the **Application level** not **at Page level**.

So you maybe are trying to do this...

```
public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
{

    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    void StartClicked(object sender, EventArgs e) 
    {
        NavigationPage page = new NavigationPage(new Page1());
        App.Current.MainPage = page;
        //App.change(page);
        //await Homepage.PopToRootAsync();
    }
}
```

Comment: I get "An object reference is required for a non-static field..." error

Comment: sorry I missed the App.Current

Comment: F#CK YES!! THANK YOU!!! I've been stuck all day on this. I will select you as best answer in 3 minutes. Thanks very much.